# setInterval for input slider does not work properly

Tags: javascript, html, setinterval

My code is a house with smoke coming out from the chimney. Tthe smoke is controlled by `setInterval` function which connects to a slider on the HTML page that is suppose to control the speed at which the smoke blows out but when you move the slider, it restarts the smoke function.

How do I set my slider to control the speed of the smoke?

here is my code:

```js
/*
    Draws each floor of the canvas.
*/
function drawFloor() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 250, 500, 250);
}
/*
    Draws the front side of the house.
*/
function drawFront() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#91AEAC";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,256); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(325,350);  //mid-right
    ctx.lineTo(319,400);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(250,387);  //bot-left
    ctx.lineTo(230,325);  //mid-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the side of the house.
*/
function drawSide() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#6F978F";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(325,350); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(412,325);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(400,375);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(319,400);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the chimney of the house.
*/
function drawChimney() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(308,217); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(337,213);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(337,250);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(312,250);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8EB0AF";
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the roof of the house.
*/
function drawRoof() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E2F35";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(278,244); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(370,221);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(425,324);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(334,350);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    // draw left line of the roof at the from
    ctx.lineWidth=10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C55463";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,250); //top
    ctx.lineTo(220,336); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // draw right line of the roof at the from
    ctx.lineWidth=10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C55463";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,245); //top
    ctx.lineTo(330,352); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
}
/*
    Draws the door of the house.
*/
function drawDoor(){
    // draws the top of the door
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(278, 351, 19, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#C18459";
    ctx.fill();
    // draws the bottom of the door
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(265,389); //bot-left
    ctx.lineTo(258.5,349);  //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(297,350);   //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(295,395);   //bot-right
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#C18459";
    ctx.fill();
    // draws the door knob
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(288, 363, 4, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = " #5F371F";
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the window of the house.
*/
function drawWindow() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="white";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,277); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(288,300);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(275,325);   //bot
    ctx.lineTo(260,301);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F9F2C5";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
/*
    Draws the Christmas tree.
*/
function drawTree() {
    /*
    // tree top
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(129,280); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,415);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,419);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree trunk
    ctx.fillStyle = "#A7673B";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(124,417); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(150,415);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(148,427);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(128,428);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    */
    // tree top 1
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(135,350); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,415);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,419);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree top 2
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(135,320); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,385);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,385);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree trunk
    ctx.fillStyle = "#A7673B";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(124,417); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(150,415);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(148,427);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(128,428);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draw the candy cane.
*/
function drawCandy() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C72828";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=8;
    ctx.moveTo(200,435);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(205,405,220,420,220,460);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
/*
    Draws the snowman in the background.
*/
function drawSnowman() {
    // snowman body
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80,250,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D8D8D8";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman head
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80,222,13,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D8D8D8";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman hat
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#F06140";
    ctx.rect(78,200,5,5);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF4444";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.moveTo(70,210); //top
    ctx.lineTo(92,210); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // snowman left eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(76,220,2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman right eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(84,220,2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman left hand
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#854B24";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.moveTo(45,235); //top
    ctx.lineTo(62,243); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // snowman right hand
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#854B24";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.moveTo(113,235); //top
    ctx.lineTo(98,243); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
}
/*
    Draws the falling snow.
*/
function drawSnow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.floor(Math.random()*(500)), Math.floor(Math.random()*(500))
                , Math.random() + 0.7, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
/*
    Draws the stars in the sky.
*/
function drawStars() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="white";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 10;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(55,115,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(90,90,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,30,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120,48,0.4,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(133,100,0.8,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150,80,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(224,155,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250,50,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(290,100,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(400,100,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(430,111,1.2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(444,48,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(450,155,0.6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(480,120,0.6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; //get the canvas dom object
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //get the context
/*
    Create objects a to g that make up the smoke.
    Each object is placed off screen, and only their shadows
    remain on the screen.
*/
var a = {   //create object a of the smoke
    x:621,  //x value
    y:250,  //y value
    r:13    //radius
}
var b = {   //create object b of the smoke
    x:595,
    y:190,
    r:13
}
var c = {   //create object c of the smoke
    x:605,
    y:180,
    r:13
}
var d = {   //create object d of the smoke
    x:620,
    y:210,
    r:13
}
var e = {   //create object e of the smoke
    x:610,
    y:170,
    r:10
}
var f = {   //create object f of the smoke
    x:610,
    y:250,
    r:8
}
var g = {   //create object g of the smoke
    x:650,
    y:200,
    r:8
}
/*
    Draws all components on the canvas.
*/
var redraw = function(){
    // draw smoke
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="#808080";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = -300;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
    ctx.arc(a.x, a.y, a.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4)";
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object b
    ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
    ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object d
    ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, d.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object e
    ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object f
    ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object g
    ctx.arc(g.x, g.y, g.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();

    drawStars();
    drawFloor();
    drawFront();
    drawSide();
    drawChimney();
    drawRoof();
    drawDoor();
    drawWindow();
    drawTree();
    drawSnowman();
    drawSnow();
    drawCandy();
    requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}
/*
    Increases each smoke component in size and moves it up the canvas.
    Returns each one to a specified position and size after it reaches
    a specified point above the canvas.
*/
function move(){
    a.y -= 8;   // move circle up canvas
    a.r += 2;   // increase circle in size
    if (a.y < -100) {   
        // if the circle reaches this position, it returns to specified position
        //   and size
        a.y = 195;  // returns to this position
        a.r = 13;   // returns to this size
    }
    b.y -= 8;
    b.r += 2;
    if (b.y < -200) {
        b.y = 195;
        b.r = 13;
    }
    c.y -= 8;
    c.r += 2;
    if (c.y < -300) {
        c.y = 195;
        c.r = 13;
    }
    d.y -= 8;
    d.r += 2;
    if (d.y < -250) {
        d.y = 195;
        d.r = 13;
    }
    e.y -= 8;
    e.r += 2;
    if (e.y < -200) {
        e.y = 195;
        e.r = 10;
    }
    f.y -= 8;
    f.r += 2;
    if (f.y < -220) {
        f.y = 200;
        f.r = 10;
    }
    g.y -= 8;
    g.r += 2;
    if (g.y < -250) {
        g.y = 195;
        g.r = 10;
    }
}
redraw();
setInterval(move, 100); // initial animation before slider is used
/*
    Uses slider output to determine how often the animate is executed.
    Reverses the number so that when user positions the slider to the right,
    the code is executed more often (faster smoke); likewise, when it is
    positioned to the left, it is executed less often (slower smoke).
*/
function outputUpdate(counter) {
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; //get the canvas dom object
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //get the context
    /*
        Create objects a to g that make up the smoke.
        Each object is placed off screen, and only their shadows
        remain on the screen.
    */
    var a = {   //create object a of the smoke
        x:621,  //x value
        y:250,  //y value
        r:13    //radius
    }
    var b = {   //create object b of the smoke
        x:595,
        y:190,
        r:13
    }
    var c = {   //create object c of the smoke
        x:605,
        y:180,
        r:13
    }
    var d = {   //create object d of the smoke
        x:620,
        y:210,
        r:13
    }
    var e = {   //create object e of the smoke
        x:610,
        y:170,
        r:10
    }
    var f = {   //create object f of the smoke
        x:610,
        y:250,
        r:8
    }
    var g = {   //create object g of the smoke
        x:650,
        y:200,
        r:8
    }
    /*
        Draws all components on the canvas.
    */
    var redraw = function(){
        // draw smoke
        ctx.save();
        ctx.shadowColor="#808080";
        ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
        ctx.shadowOffsetX = -300;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
        ctx.arc(a.x, a.y, a.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4)";
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object b
        ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
        ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object d
        ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, d.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object e
        ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object f
        ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object g
        ctx.arc(g.x, g.y, g.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();

        drawStars();
        drawFloor();
        drawFront();
        drawSide();
        drawChimney();
        drawRoof();
        drawDoor();
        drawWindow();
        drawTree();
        drawSnowman();
        drawSnow();
        requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
    }
    /*
        Increases each smoke component in size and moves it up the canvas.
        Returns each one to a specified position and size after it reaches
        a specified point above the canvas.
    */
    function move(){
        a.y -= 8;   // move circle up canvas
        a.r += 2;   // increase circle in size
        if (a.y < -100) {   
            // if the circle reaches this position, it returns to specified position
            //   and size
            a.y = 195;  // returns to this position
            a.r = 13;   // returns to this size
        }
        b.y -= 8;
        b.r += 2;
        if (b.y < -200) {
            b.y = 195;
            b.r = 13;
        }
        c.y -= 8;
        c.r += 2;
        if (c.y < -300) {
            c.y = 195;
            c.r = 13;
        }
        d.y -= 8;
        d.r += 2;
        if (d.y < -250) {
            d.y = 195;
            d.r = 13;
        }
        e.y -= 8;
        e.r += 2;
        if (e.y < -200) {
            e.y = 195;
            e.r = 10;
        }
        f.y -= 8;
        f.r += 2;
        if (f.y < -220) {
            f.y = 200;
            f.r = 10;
        }
        g.y -= 8;
        g.r += 2;
        if (g.y < -250) {
            g.y = 195; 
            g.r = 10;
        }
    }
    redraw();
    document.querySelector('#speed').value = counter;
    setInterval(function(){ move() }, (200-counter));
}
```

```css
body {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #4A6485;
    display: block;
}
#fakeLinks {
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
    font-family: arial;
    top: -10;
    left: -25;
}
span {
    color: black;
}
#icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 12;
    left: -5;
}
#setSpeed {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:180;
    right:0;
    bottom:1000;
}
#speed {
    color: white;
}
#info {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- stars or snow; separate function
for smoke - does not work with range?; stars behind smoke; get rid of range #
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>smoke</title>
    <div id="fakeLinks">
      <img id="icon" src="Images/houseicon.png" alt="houseicon">vancouver, BC 
      <span>></span> housing <span>></span> for rent</div>
      <h2>Get out of the cold and stay at our winter vacation rental!</h2>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <input id="setSpeed" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100"
            oninput="outputUpdate(value)" name="sliderInput"/>
        <output for="setSpeed" id="speed" name="sliderOutput"></output>
      </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/house.css">
</head>
<!--Commented out for use in snippet     <script src="house.js"></script>  -->
<body onLoad="drawSnow()">
    <div id ="info">
        <p>Everything is completed. We have a working fireplace and electricity.</p>
        <p>There were no major challenges in the construction of this house.</p></br>
        <p>For more information please contact: </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally, what is expected is for you to provide a **minimal** [mcve] which isolates the issue that you are having.

Answer (score 1):

In `outputUpdate()` you re-define a huge number of variables, along with the `move()` and `redraw()` functions.  The only difference is that in the re-defined `redraw()` you don't call `drawCandy()`. This is a ridiculous way to do whatever it is you are trying to do by redefining these. I'm not sure what that is. If you are really wanting to not call `drawCandy()` then pass an argument, or set a global variable. Don't duplicate the code. Duplicating the code was causing significant problems.

The problem you are having with your `setInterval()` is that you are not clearing any interval prior to setting a new interval which updates at a different rate.  This results in you creating a large number of interval timers which bog down the CPU. To solve this, I just used the brute force method of creating the global variable `moveIntervalId` to store the interval ID, and then called [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) prior to both [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) calls.

I also moved drawing the smoke into its own function.

```js
var moveIntervalId;

/*
    Draws each floor of the canvas.
*/
function drawFloor() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 250, 500, 250);
}
/*
    Draws the front side of the house.
*/
function drawFront() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#91AEAC";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,256); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(325,350);  //mid-right
    ctx.lineTo(319,400);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(250,387);  //bot-left
    ctx.lineTo(230,325);  //mid-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the side of the house.
*/
function drawSide() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#6F978F";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(325,350); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(412,325);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(400,375);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(319,400);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the chimney of the house.
*/
function drawChimney() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(308,217); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(337,213);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(337,250);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(312,250);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8EB0AF";
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the roof of the house.
*/
function drawRoof() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E2F35";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(278,244); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(370,221);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(425,324);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(334,350);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    // draw left line of the roof at the from
    ctx.lineWidth=10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C55463";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,250); //top
    ctx.lineTo(220,336); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // draw right line of the roof at the from
    ctx.lineWidth=10;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C55463";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,245); //top
    ctx.lineTo(330,352); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
}
/*
    Draws the door of the house.
*/
function drawDoor(){
    // draws the top of the door
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(278, 351, 19, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#C18459";
    ctx.fill();
    // draws the bottom of the door
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(265,389); //bot-left
    ctx.lineTo(258.5,349);  //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(297,350);   //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(295,395);   //bot-right
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#C18459";
    ctx.fill();
    // draws the door knob
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(288, 363, 4, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = " #5F371F";
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draws the window of the house.
*/
function drawWindow() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="white";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 20;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(275,277); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(288,300);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(275,325);   //bot
    ctx.lineTo(260,301);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#F9F2C5";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
/*
    Draws the Christmas tree.
*/
function drawTree() {
    /*
    // tree top
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(129,280); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,415);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,419);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree trunk
    ctx.fillStyle = "#A7673B";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(124,417); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(150,415);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(148,427);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(128,428);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    */
    // tree top 1
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(135,350); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,415);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,419);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree top 2
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(135,320); //tip
    ctx.lineTo(179,385);  //right
    ctx.lineTo(90,385);   //left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#8E9D2A";
    ctx.fill();
    // tree trunk
    ctx.fillStyle = "#A7673B";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(124,417); //top-left
    ctx.lineTo(150,415);  //top-right
    ctx.lineTo(148,427);   //bot-right
    ctx.lineTo(128,428);   //bot-left
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
/*
    Draw the candy cane.
*/
function drawCandy() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#C72828";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=8;
    ctx.moveTo(200,435);
    ctx.bezierCurveTo(205,405,220,420,220,460);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
/*
    Draws the snowman in the background.
*/
function drawSnowman() {
    // snowman body
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80,250,20,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D8D8D8";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman head
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(80,222,13,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#D8D8D8";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman hat
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle="#F06140";
    ctx.rect(78,200,5,5);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF4444";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.moveTo(70,210); //top
    ctx.lineTo(92,210); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // snowman left eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(76,220,2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman right eye
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(84,220,2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fill();
    // snowman left hand
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#854B24";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.moveTo(45,235); //top
    ctx.lineTo(62,243); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
    // snowman right hand
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#854B24";
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.moveTo(113,235); //top
    ctx.lineTo(98,243); //bot
    ctx.stroke();
}
/*
    Draws the falling snow.
*/
function drawSnow() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(Math.floor(Math.random()*(500)), Math.floor(Math.random()*(500))
                , Math.random() + 0.7, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
/*
    Draw the smoke
*/
function drawSmoke() {
    // draw smoke
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="#808080";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 40;
    ctx.shadowOffsetX = -300;
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear canvas
    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
    ctx.arc(a.x, a.y, a.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.4)";
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object b
    ctx.arc(b.x, b.y, b.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object c
    ctx.arc(c.x, c.y, c.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object d
    ctx.arc(d.x, d.y, d.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object e
    ctx.arc(e.x, e.y, e.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object f
    ctx.arc(f.x, f.y, f.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();  //draw the object g
    ctx.arc(g.x, g.y, g.r, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
/*
    Draws the stars in the sky.
*/
function drawStars() {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.shadowColor="white";
    ctx.shadowBlur = 10;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(55,115,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(90,90,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(100,30,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(120,48,0.4,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(133,100,0.8,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(150,80,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(224,155,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250,50,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(290,100,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(400,100,1,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(430,111,1.2,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(444,48,0.5,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(450,155,0.6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(480,120,0.6,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore();
}
var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0]; //get the canvas dom object
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); //get the context
/*
    Create objects a to g that make up the smoke.
    Each object is placed off screen, and only their shadows
    remain on the screen.
*/
var a = {   //create object a of the smoke
    x:621,  //x value
    y:250,  //y value
    r:13    //radius
}
var b = {   //create object b of the smoke
    x:595,
    y:190,
    r:13
}
var c = {   //create object c of the smoke
    x:605,
    y:180,
    r:13
}
var d = {   //create object d of the smoke
    x:620,
    y:210,
    r:13
}
var e = {   //create object e of the smoke
    x:610,
    y:170,
    r:10
}
var f = {   //create object f of the smoke
    x:610,
    y:250,
    r:8
}
var g = {   //create object g of the smoke
    x:650,
    y:200,
    r:8
}
/*
    Draws all components on the canvas.
*/
function redraw(){
    drawSmoke();
    drawStars();
    drawFloor();
    drawFront();
    drawSide();
    drawChimney();
    drawRoof();
    drawDoor();
    drawWindow();
    drawTree();
    drawSnowman();
    drawSnow();
    drawCandy();
    requestAnimationFrame(redraw);
}
 
/*
    Increases each smoke component in size and moves it up the canvas.
    Returns each one to a specified position and size after it reaches
    a specified point above the canvas.
*/
function move(){
    a.y -= 8;   // move circle up canvas
    a.r += 2;   // increase circle in size
    if (a.y < -100) {   
        // if the circle reaches this position, it returns to specified position
        //   and size
        a.y = 195;  // returns to this position
        a.r = 13;   // returns to this size
    }
    b.y -= 8;
    b.r += 2;
    if (b.y < -200) {
        b.y = 195;
        b.r = 13;
    }
    c.y -= 8;
    c.r += 2;
    if (c.y < -300) {
        c.y = 195;
        c.r = 13;
    }
    d.y -= 8;
    d.r += 2;
    if (d.y < -250) {
        d.y = 195;
        d.r = 13;
    }
    e.y -= 8;
    e.r += 2;
    if (e.y < -200) {
        e.y = 195;
        e.r = 10;
    }
    f.y -= 8;
    f.r += 2;
    if (f.y < -220) {
        f.y = 200;
        f.r = 10;
    }
    g.y -= 8;
    g.r += 2;
    if (g.y < -250) {
        g.y = 195;
        g.r = 10;
    }

}
redraw();
clearInterval(moveIntervalId);
moveIntervalId = setInterval(move, 100); // initial animation before slider is used
/*
    Uses slider output to determine how often the animate is executed.
    Reverses the number so that when user positions the slider to the right,
    the code is executed more often (faster smoke); likewise, when it is
    positioned to the left, it is executed less often (slower smoke).
*/
function outputUpdate(counter) {
    document.querySelector('#speed').value = counter;
    clearInterval(moveIntervalId);
    moveIntervalId = setInterval(move, (200-counter)); 
}
```

```css
body {
    padding-left: 2em;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: #4A6485;
    display: block;
}
#fakeLinks {
    position: relative;
    color: blue;
    font-family: arial;
    top: -10;
    left: -25;
}
span {
    color: black;
}
#icon {
    position: relative;
    top: 12;
    left: -5;
}
#setSpeed {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:180;
    right:0;
    bottom:1000;
}
#speed {
    color: white;
}
#info {
    position: relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<!-- stars or snow; separate function
for smoke - does not work with range?; stars behind smoke; get rid of range #
-->
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Luong, Jessica | Qin, Ashley</title>
    <div id="fakeLinks">
      <img id="icon" src="Images/houseicon.png" alt="houseicon">vancouver, BC 
      <span>></span> housing <span>></span> for rent</div>
      <h2>Get out of the cold and stay at our winter vacation rental!</h2>
      <div class="wrapper">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
        <input id="setSpeed" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100"
            oninput="outputUpdate(value)" name="sliderInput"/>
        <output for="setSpeed" id="speed" name="sliderOutput"></output>
      </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style/house.css">
</head>
<!--Commented out for use in snippet     <script src="house.js"></script>  -->
<body onLoad="drawSnow()">
    <div id ="info">
        <p>Everything is completed. We have a working fireplace and electricity.</p>
        <p>There were no major challenges in the construction of this house.</p></br>
        <p>For more information please contact: </p>
        <p> </p>
        <p></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this line: document.querySelector('#speed').value = counter;

I tested this, working in FireFox.

Comment: This answer does not work.  The code as written reads the value (it is padded in as a parameter).  As the OP has written it, this portion of the code is correct. You just can't see the output number that this code is changing because the text is colored `white` in the CSS. If you change the CSS, you will be able to see it.